# git workflow after commit

Tags: git, github

I have a local clone of a remote repository with master and `branch1`.

`master` was the latest until I did some work on `branch1` that I committed (remember, all local). after committing my `branch1` work, I’m kind of confused how to go about later steps.

My thinking is to switch to `master`, and do a `git merge branch1`, and then do a push of my local copy of `master` to remote (my local `master` is up to date with remote `master`). Is this correct or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why choose to do `git checkout`, `git merge`, and then `git push` when you could just do `git push` ?  I'd prefer the workflow that results in the least amount of commands to type

Comment: I didn't realize I can just do git push by itself, it'll do the merge as well?

Comment: You have to pull/merge/rebase if your upstream has changed.  If you aren't working on your local master you don't need to use two local branches though which eliminates the checkout/merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on your [workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows). Do you have multiple devs working on the project or just you?

If you are the only developer working on the project, your suggestion is fine. You branch locally, perform your changes, merge, push.

Another approach is to create remote branches, push local to the remote branch, and then merge together (if you are using Stash, BitBucket, or some other remote hosting technology). The latter approach is nice if you are performing collaborative code reviews or need to share your work with a team. You can also push to the remote branch to have a backup.

Comment: quick question, after merging, do I have to do a commit with master? or I can just push?

Comment: A merge does not require a commit because you are merely bringing commits into the commit history of the target (e.g. master).

Comment: Also, a successful merge does not require a commit afterwards because a post-merge commit is automatically created by git.

Comment: Unless you fast-forward in which case the merge-commit is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

When I am working on a project even solo I try to keep off of master for work. Resist the temptation.

Whether it is my own project or someone else's I have been cloning it, creating a new `develop` branch and working there and than merging `develop` into `master`.

I will also frequently create feature branches off of `develop` and I do this so that if I need to tweak something on the current running code, I can stash my changes, switch to `develop`, make the fix and merge that into `master` and still be able to go back to the feature I was working on.

My feature branches never get pushed to origin. Once the feature is merged into develop, I will delete the feature branch.

If I do work on the `develop` branch and have a feature branch I am working on, I will generally rebase my feature branch on the `develop` branch.

Comment: I'm trying to resist the temptation ;)

Comment: Workflows can change depending on the people working on it, but the links given are pretty good starting points and it is a good idea to understand why people have a certain workflow since you will come across them on many open source projects.

Answer (score 3):

I generally use this workflow. Assuming that a repo exists on your system’s home directory under the name `my_project`, go into it like this:

```
cd ~/my_project
```

Once in that project I do a check for branches:

```
git branch -a
```

That will list all branches. That step can be skipped if you know for sure there’s no other branches you want to deal with. Now, make sure you are on master like this:

```
git checkout master
```

Okay, good? Now let’s checkout a `develop` branch like this:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

And now you will simultaneously create and checkout a branch called `develop`.

Now in develop do whatever you want to do. Commit as appropriate and when appropriate. Just do your thing.

Now, when it comes time to merge with `master` checkout `master` like this:

```
git checkout master
```

And while in there, you now have two choices. You could do a standard merge like this:

```
git merge develop
```

So now `master` will be merged with `develop`. But man times I prefer to use the no fast forward (`--no-ff`) option like this:

```
git merge --no-ff develop
```

This site [explains it in detail](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), but the long and short of it is that by using `--no-ff` you basically place an extra commit into the merge that marks when that merge happened. The main benefit of this is that if something screws up down the line and you need to investigate—or roll back—what happened, the `--no-ff` related commit is clear to spot and roll back to. Much easier than trying to decipher the tons of commits you might have in the repo.

The `--no-ff` becomes even more valuable as you work with others on a decentralized team. By everyone on the mean using `--no-ff` commits for merges, everyone’s life becomes easier when dealing with post-commit related issues.

That said, I often do the plain `git merge develop` when I am working on simple projects on my own where I make a new adjustment once in a blue moon.

Git is ultimately a source control management system, so how you handle commits basically rests on your comfort level in dealing with issues that will require rollback if/when the come along.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct way to merge changes from `branch1` into your `master` branch. There is some good documentation on git merging [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging).